# Adding google maps marker from nested array

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've successfully added markers to a map using this code:

```
var film = [
[ "12 Years a Slave",-90.0715323,29.9510658,"2013"],
[ "12 Years a Slave",-90.7197143,30.0110809,"2013"]];

for (i = 0; i < film.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(film[i][2], film[i][1]),
});
```

I've changed my array to a nested format, because I'd like to be able to turn on the markers for just one film at a time, not always all at once.

```
var film = [["12 Years a Slave","2013",[[-90.3517469,29.9429828],[-90.1525373,29.9502543]]],
["The Life of Emile Zola","1937",[[-117.7603323,33.5141933],[-118.3387185,34.1486546]]]];
```

How do I turn on all the markers at once, or turn it on for just one film? Do I need a second type of for loop inside this loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you would need a second for loop to go through each film's positions (since now a film has more than 1 position).

Based on your above code, this should do the trick:

```js
// Go through each film
for (i = 0; i < film.length; i++) {
  // Display the film marker.
  displayFilm(film[i])
}

/**
 * Function to display a single film.
 *
 * @param filmData array of film data structured as (name, year, list of positions)
 */
function displayFilm(filmData) {
  var positions = filmData[2];
  // Go through all positions of a film
  for (j = 0; j < positions.length; j++) {
    // Show marker
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(positions[j][1], positions[j][0])
    });
  }
}
```

To display a single film, use the `displayFilm` function. To display all of them, use the first for loop that calls the function for each film.

Comment: Apologies haven't had access to my laptop to try yet - will test tonight and let you know - many thanks for your answer.

Comment: Glad to hear that ;)